# Unwanted transparent Navbar

Tags: html, css

I want a non-transparent navbar. When I add `position: fixed;` to my navbar I see that when I scroll that the navbar is transparent. How to avoid this?

**GitHub Repo**: https://github.com/CalogerN/Conquer

**Live Preview**: https://calogern.github.io/Conquer/ (under construction)

I tried `opacity: 1` but it does nothing.

```css
.navbar {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 78px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #383e4c;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: 700;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li><button type="button" name="button" class="nav- 
    btn">Homepage</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" name="button" class="nav-btn">About Us</button>
    </li>
    <li><button type="button" name="button" class="nav-btn">Services</button>
    </li>
    <li><button type="button" name="button" class="nav-btn">Contact</button>
    </li>
    <li><button type="button" name="button" class="nav-btn">External</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: have you checked for any javascript dynamically adding inline styles to the nav ?

Comment: using bootstrap? or jquery?, which version?

Comment: i don't see a transparent nav https://codepen.io/srsandy/pen/eqEKqr

Comment: I am using boilerplate html, maybe is this? I don't understand it fully, I use it because in my FED course they said to always use it because it contains normalizing files

Comment: I'll upload my code in a GitHub repo and show it

Comment: add the link in the question @CalogeroNapoli

Comment: https://github.com/CalogerN/Conquer Live Preview 
   https://calogern.github.io/Conquer/ (under construction)

Comment: @CalogeroNapoli are you worried about the CONQUER text

Comment: I noticed that the transparency is only with the conquer text @Sandeep Ranjan

Comment: The navbar is never transparent I always see the blue color in the background

Comment: So you want to solve the conquer text part right? @CalogeroNapoli

Comment: https://ibb.co/qYbm4k4 Here the link of the img how I see it @Sandeep Ranjan

Comment: @CalogeroNapoli I too see it that way. The problem not about transparent. It's about the positions and z-Index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just simply add `z-index:99` to your navbar !

```
.navbar {
list-style: none;
margin-top: 0;
height: 78px;
font-size: 20px;
background-color: #383e4c;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 0px;
font-family: "Open Sans";
font-weight: 700;
position: fixed;
/* opacity: 1; */
z-index: 99;
width: 100%;
```

}

Comment: Can you explain better? Why only the conquer part is being showed that way and not the other parts? @adel

Comment: elements are positioned, they can overlap other elements. your Conquer text got a relative position. and i don't why you needed  relative position on  these elements! @CalogeroNapoli

Comment: But I changed only the y axis position, I didn't touch the z-axis position using z-index on Conquer and the sub-heading. I didn't know it that worked that way. Because I'm trying to clone a website template for exercise and in that template the text wasn't exactly in the middle. @adel

Comment: to make things not exactly in the middle. you use proper `margins`. @CalogeroNapoli not positions.

Comment: Margin is for changing the distance between elements, here I just wanted to position a heading and sub-heading some pixels on top of their normal position in the flow.

Comment: yep exactly he don't need to use relative position on the text, just use `margin-top:-50px` and then you don't need to add z-index @SandeepRanjan  @Calogero Napoli

Answer (score 0):

1. When you're using Bootstrap read documentation carefully ;)
2. When you want fixed top/bottom navbar WITHOUT transparency instead of overriding .navbar class in your's csses by adding position:fixed apply ready-to-use Bootstrap class fixed-top/fixed-bottom/sticky-top applying them to your html/jsx Bootstrap element
3. Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#placement

Comment: I am not using bootstrap. Only HTML & CSS.

Answer (score 0):

So here there is nothing to do with transparency.

Your `.navbar` has `position: fixed;`.
Here you have the problem with **vertical stacking order of elements that overlap**.

You are having that problem because in your code you have a `.hero`. The elements inside `.hero` have `position: relative;`.

You can just solve this problem by adding a `z-index: 1;` to your `.navbar`.

The `z-index` property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

> Note: `z-index` only works on positioned elements.

```
.navbar {
list-style: none;
margin-top: 0;
height: 78px;
font-size: 20px;
background-color: #383e4c;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 0px;
font-family: "Open Sans";
font-weight: 700;
position: fixed;
/* opacity: 1; */
z-index: 99;
width: 100%;
}
```

Read More about [Z-Index](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: I know about z-index, but why it doesn't overlap with the rest of the page? @Sandeep Ranjan

Comment: because the rest of the elements do have `position: static;` which is like 0 levels. and you have stacked two things on top of that

Comment: check the MDN Web Docs link you will understand better.